# raspberry pi hotspot script not working

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, wifi, hotspot

I use RaspberryPi 3. I would like to make it a hotspot if it can't find [RaspbarryPi 3 auto wifi hotspot if no internet](http://www.raspberryconnect.com/network/item/315-rpi3-auto-wifi-hotspot-if-no-internet). The tutorial shows a code to edit rc.local file.

Please find my code of rc.local file below:
http://pastebin.com/3mRXHCUG

When I debug the file, it shows error at line 39 as " **Syntax error: "(" unexpected**"

The code of line 39 is as follow:

`ssids= ("Bhavik","iBall-Baton")`

So RaspberryPi always crates hotspot no matter if the specified Wifi connections are available.

Kindly help me. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using square or curly braces instead of parentheses?

Comment: Yes. they also don't work

Comment: Try `ssids[0]="Bhavik"; ssids[1]="iBall-Baton"`.  Does that work?

Comment: No it does not work.

Comment: I just got the problem!  You forgot to change your top line from `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash`!  BTW, a mistake I have made dozens of times...  :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the way you are attempting to define your array.  Basically, `rc.local` is written in bash scripting, and defining an array as

```
ssids= ("Bhavik","iBall-Baton")
```

isn't bash; it won't work.  If you want to define the array manually, define it this way:

```
ssids[0]="Bhavik";
ssids[1]="iBall-Baton";
```

Then your code ought to work.

Comment: I face error saying, /etc/rc.local: 39: /etc/rc.local: ssids[0]=Bhavik: not found
/etc/rc.local: 40: /etc/rc.local: ssids[1]=iBall-Baton: not found
/etc/rc.local: 42: /etc/rc.local: Bad substitution

Comment: Wait, did you put Bhavik and iBall-Baton in quotes?  It looks like the code is trying to substitute in values from non-existent variables.  Try putthing them in quotes.

Comment: Sorry I could not understand the last comment. Did you mean to put in single quote ?

Comment: @HarshIT, no, I meant, did you put in `ssids[0]="Bhavik";` or `ssids[0]=Bhavik;`?  Because you'll need the quotes in there, otherwise bash looks at Bhavik as a variable.

Comment: I put  ssids[0]="Bhavik";

Comment: Hmm, odd.  Still looking...

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed a remarkably simple issue:  You forgot to swap out the line

```
#!/bin/sh
```

for the line

```
#!/bin/bash
```

This means that the script is using the sh coding rather than the powerloaded sh scripting called bash.  Your array should work any way you define it if you have your script defined correctly.